# Is Lanfeust Quest compatible with the canon of Lanfeust of Troy?

Tags: lanfeust-quest

I was trying to look up information for another question I have on [Lanfeust Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanfeust_Quest). I learned that the animation is an adaption of a french comic book which itself comes from another long running french comic book series called [Lanfeust of Troy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanfeust_of_Troy).

While I was looking up information about Thanos, I read that he was actually some Baron and that his teleportation power doesn't let him carry personal belongings yet I have seen him teleport with his sword.

I am wondering if Lanfeust Quest is compatible with the canon of Lanfeust of Troy? If not, then what makes it incompatible?

Comment: For the record, cannon = a big gun, canon = a body of work.

Comment: @Richard And Canon = a large electronics company. ;-)